# baseUrl and paths in typescript - how

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, path, require

I've started an application in typescript. I've learned about some features of TS and it looked like something, that could help me, hovewer, I don't work like I would expect. The documentation of TS says something about **Path mapping** in **Module resolution** chapter. This module mapping can, if I understand it correctly, save me few or even lot of double-dots in `import`. So I have created a "inc" directory with one file (at this time), that will be included in multiple files in multiple directories. Into tsconfig I've written following:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
    "@inc/*": [ "inc/*" ]
}
```

Now, I would expect, that using `import { X } from "@inc/somefile"` (even from file resting somewhere deep in folder tree) would result in importing that `export X` from ./inc/somefile.ts (or .js, when runnning).

Hovewer, the compiler/transpiler will leave the `import` statement intact, so when I try to run this code using `node.js`, it will die because there is no `@inc/somefile` - node doesn't read tsconfig and tsc doesn't create any mapping functions.

I can, of course, read and parse the `path` element by hand in some kind of require wrapper, but I believe there is something I'm doing wrong and/or better way to achieve this.

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: No. It's currently unresolvable (uff, is that a real word?) by vanilla TS, more on that on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866

Answer (score 3):

Remember that

> if you then try to exeute the compiled files with node (or ts-node), it will only look in the node_modules folders all the way up to the root of the filesystem and thus will not find the modules specified by paths in `tsconfig`.  -- introduced in tsconfig-paths readme.

In conclusion, directly require [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) into dependencies list and load tsconfig file on run could be a quick solution.

Comment: OMG! This is the only **correct answer**, I was searching for hours! This little thing was almost driving me crazy! xD Thank you so much!